# Вывести результаты пяти разных арифметических действий над двумя введенными числам Swift

Tags: swift

Что не так, не могу понять, почему не работает?

```
import Foundation
func printResults(a: Int, b: Int) → Void {

    print (a + b) = \(a + b)
    print (a - b) = \(a - b)
    print (a * b) = \(a * b)
    print (a / b) = \(a / b)
    print (a % b) = \(a % b)
}

print printResults(a: 2, b: 3)
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вы забыли поставить кавычки в print, например print "(a + b) = \\(a + b)"

Answer (score 1):

1. У принтов внутри функции не хватает скобок и кавычек.
2. Если функция ничего не возвращает, то Void писать не нужно.
3. При вызове функции принт не нужен, так как ваша функция ничего не возвращает и соотвественно принту просто нечего печатать. Просто вызываете саму функцию и она своими внутренними принтами печатает то, что вам нужно.

Вот так правильно (остальные принты внутри функции по аналогии):

```
import Foundation

func printResults(a: Int, b: Int) {

    print("(a + b) = \(a + b)")
//  Остальные по аналогии
}

printResults(a: 2, b: 3)
```